# Problem with C program not exiting at integer count 150 by using a while loop

Tags: c

I was wondering if I could get some help with a problem that I am having.

Basically, I am trying to end my program by using a while loop when the people count gets to 150.

My math seems to be right, but for some reason, the program ends when it gets to people count 276.

Can anyone help with this issue? Thanks!

Code Input:

```c
int main () { 
    // declare variables
    int weeks=0, people=5;
    while (people < 150) {
        weeks++;
        people=(people-weeks)*2;
        printf("On week %d Professor Rabnud's Social Media Group has %d people\n", weeks, people);
    } 
    // end program
    return 0; 
}
```

Code Output:

```
On week 1 Professor Rabnud's Social Media Group has 8 people
On week 2 Professor Rabnud's Social Media Group has 12 people
On week 3 Professor Rabnud's Social Media Group has 18 people
On week 4 Professor Rabnud's Social Media Group has 28 people
On week 5 Professor Rabnud's Social Media Group has 46 people
On week 6 Professor Rabnud's Social Media Group has 80 people
On week 7 Professor Rabnud's Social Media Group has 146 people
On week 8 Professor Rabnud's Social Media Group has 276 people
```

Comment: The loop is last executed when `people` reaches 146. Then you change the value of people and print out additional output.

Answer (score 0):

```c
int main () { 
    // declare variables
    int weeks=0, people=5;
    while (people < 150) {
        weeks++;
        people=(people-weeks)*2;
        printf("On week %d Professor Rabnud's Social Media Group has %d people\n", weeks, people);
    } 
    // end program
    return 0; 
}
```

As you can see, when `week == 7` then `people == 146` Because `146 < 150` is `true`, the loop is executed again. First, it increment `week` so now `week == 8`, then, it caculated `people`. `(146 - 8) * 2 == 276`, so `people` is now `276` Then it executed the `printf()` statement. Only now,  `276 < 150` is `false`, then the loop terminated.

Because we know when `week == 1` then `people == 8` we can do this:

```c
int main () { 
    // declare variables
    int weeks=1, people=8;
    while (people < 150) {
        printf("On week %d Professor Rabnud's Social Media Group has %d people\n", weeks, people);
        weeks++;
        people=(people-weeks)*2;
    } 
    // end program
    return 0; 
}
```